# Comparar 2 datas

Tags: php, html, css

Estou tentando fazer este código funcionar corretamente, mas o mesmo pelo que eu percebi só compara o dia pois se estiver maior que o dia atual funciona corretamente, mas se estiver menor que o dia atual apresenta o erro "A sua conta expirou" é como se ele não comparasse o mês nem o ano!
Mas no caso os outros tópicos não me servem pois eles são para comparar 2 datas diferentes que esta armazenada na variavel, minha data é do banco de dados!

```
$vencimento = $dado['vencimento'];

if (date("d/m/Y") > $vencimento) {

        echo "A sua conta expirou";

    }
else {

        echo "A sua conta ainda não expirou";

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você poderia fazer da seguinte forma baixo, usando a classe nativa DateTime do PHP:

```
<?php

$vencimento = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '22/02/2018');
$hoje = new DateTime();

if ($hoje > $vencimento) {
    echo "A sua conta expirou";
} else {
    echo "A sua conta ainda não expirou";
}
```

Comment: mas no caso minha data seria a do banco de dados no caso:
$vencimento = $dado['vencimento'];

Comment: É só colocar no formato que está vindo do banco de dados nos parâmetros do método DateTime::createFromFormat('formato', '$dado['vencimento']');

Comment: Resolvido, obrigado, para quem quiser usar o meu codigo se estiver com problema, esta ai:
$vencimento = $dado['vencimento'];
$vencimento1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $vencimento);
if ($hoje > $vencimento1) {
echo "...";
}